# In JavaScript, how does an object assigned to a variable keeps track of future mutations?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

I have been practicing data structures with JavaScript recently and I found a snippet of code that I can't wrap my head around. I understand that when you assign an object to a variable, and then mutate the object, the original variable can "see" those mutations because when you assign the object to the variable you are not cloning the object, you are just passing a reference to it. However, the following code baffles my mind:

```
function ListNode(val, next) {
  this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
  this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
}

let tempList = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 100];

let point = new ListNode(tempList[0]);
let head = point;

for (let i = 1; i < tempList.length; i++) {
  point.next = new ListNode(tempList[i])
  point = point.next;
}

console.log(head); // Outputs the Linked List 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 4 -> 100
```

So when I try to follow the logic in my head, I picture it as follows:

In the first iteration, `head` and `point` hold the following information:

```
{
  val: 1,
  next: null
}
```

In the second iteration, `point` first holds this information:

```
{
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 1,
    next: null
  }
}
```

and so does `head`, but then the next step is what is confusing me. In my head, I'm overriding the current value of `point` with the newly created Node in the step before, so the variable should look like this:

```
{
  val: 1,
  next: null
}
```

and `head` since it's just holding a reference from `point` should look like that as well. HOWEVER, `head` looks as follows:

```
{
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 1,
    next: null
  }
}
```

and as the iterations keep going, obviously, `head` keeps track of all the linked nodes. That's the desired behavior, but I do not fully comprehend HOW that happens. Can somebody explain me why this is the case?

Comment: "*`head` since it's just holding a reference from `point` should look like that as well*" - no, `head` does not reference `point`. After `head = point`, both variables do hold a reference *to the object* in memory. Not to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript variables don't bind to other variables. They bind to the **value** of the variable at the time, which in your case is the initial `point` object.

It sounds like your mental model is telling you
`head` -> `point` -> {} when in reality **both point to the same object**, therefore binding `point` to a new object does not affect `head`.

`head` is not in the loop, therefore you're never actually updating the value of `head` once you've bound it to the first object `point` is bound to.

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign `point` it doesn't affect the reference in `head`. It still refers to the first `ListNode` that was created.

It's no different from doing something like this:

```
let point = 1;
let head = point;
point = point + 1;
```

Reassigning `point` doesn't change the value of `head`, even though they were equivalent at first.

If you're familiar with languages like C or C++, you can think of the reference as being like a pointer. You start with two pointers to the same address, then reassign one of them; that won't change the other pointer.